# Is there a script to change y-axis values of the chart to arabic values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm Doing line and pie chart but i need it in Arabic language on y-axis.

```
        $('button').on('click', function(e) {
            $('#pie-chart3').empty();
            var type = $(this).data('type')

            //data for month 
            , month = [
                    {label: 'English', value: 30},
                    {label: "Italian", value: 40},
                    {label: "French", value: 30}
                ]


            //data for week 
            , week = [
                    {label: 'English', value: 60},
                    {label: "Italian", value: 40}
                ]

            //data for date 
            , day = [
                    {label: 'English', value: 90},
                ]

            , data = {
                month: month,
                week: week,
                day: day
                }

                Morris.Donut({
                element: 'pie-chart3',
                resize: true,
                data: data[type],

                //color of pie chart 
                labelColor: "#9CC4E4",
                colors: ['#1bb99a', '#3db9dc', '#ebeff2']
            })
            ;

        });

</script>
```

I change value of label:English to label:انجليزيه and expect output will change but the whole chart just disappeared.

Comment: Can you create [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It will much help us to help you..

Comment: Just please clarify what exactly you **want** to happen and what **actually** happened. Is the **numbers** (because you mention the numbers in the question's title) or the **label**''s text.

Comment: I changed it all i need is that change values of y-axis at line chart and label numbers of pie chart

Answer (score 0):

you can use css font family property to change numbers in Arabic.

1. add Arabic or Persian font Like B Nazanin or B Koodak ([Download B Koodak Font](https://www.fontyab.com/wp-content/uploads/B-Koodak.zip))  you can find it and download it by search it in google
2. add css style sheet  `* {font-family: B Nazanin;}

Comment: I don't think that OP talking about the numbers but changing the **label** text `change value of label:English to label:انجليزيه `

Comment: add css style sheet  to label. ex label {font-family: B Nazanin;}

Comment: it will convert English number View to Arabic display of number.

Comment: I mean as @MoshFeu Said and I tried this css style that you suggest but doesn't change anything

Comment: you ask this question "Is there a script to change numbers of the chart to arabic numbers?" change number. may be you want to change English Date to Arabic Date. is that your question?

Comment: @Norhan Did you do step 1?

Comment: @AliHafezi No I mean the label of the pie chart change to Arabic language as I said at the example

Comment: @MoshFeu I will use what you mentioned and try it

Comment: the label is a simple number or Date?

Comment: It is simple number

Comment: do you add any persian or arabic fonts?

Comment: you should change your font. that can solve your problem

Comment: you can download B koodak Font from this Link https://www.fontyab.com/wp-content/uploads/B-Koodak.zip